# Handle "slide to view" of local notification from lock screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I'm attempting to handle a local notification in my iOS application. I've read through the following document(s):

[Scheduling, Registering, and Handling Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13)

Here is the code to generate the notification:

```
UILocalNotification *notify = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notify.alertBody = @"Alert Title";
notify.alertAction = @"view";
notify.repeatInterval = 0;
notify.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notify.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notify];
```

This code is executed while the app is in the background, i.e. after the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` function was called. The notification gets created just fine, I can see it on the lock screen, however performing the action - `slide to view` doesn't seem to work as I expect.

According to the documentation handling the notification should call `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. However, when I slide to view, `applicationWillEnterForeground:` actually gets called.

Could someone please point me in the right direction? I'm clearly doing something wrong, I can't seem to figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` will only be called if your app is not launched already. While it is true that the `options` will include info on notifications if that is what ended up launching the app, what you want is to handle your local notification logic here:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Source: [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidReceiveLocalNotification%3a)

Comment: I knew I was missing something, thanks for pointing it out. That solved it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the execution state `applicationWillEnterForeground` is called. I don't think you would see `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` again.

App load from device off:

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
applicationDidBecomeActive:
```

Home button pressed:

```
applicationWillResignActive:
applicationDidEnterBackground:
```

Re-enter app:

```
applicationWillEnterForeground:
applicationDidBecomeActive:
```